# indexing a logical vector in r with a condition

Tags: r, mean

I have a small dataset in which I need to find the average value of the individuals' heights and index it in a logical vector in which I can then add up how many people are above that average value.

I've already got average using `mean(heights$height)`

But I'm not understanding how to index it into a vector in which I pull just the above-average values. Can someone please help me?

I've already tried to use

```
ind <- heights > mean(heights$heights)
```

and

```
ind <- heights > mean
```

But it's not correct. So, I need a little help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your data frame is `heights` and the column in question is named `height` this should give you a logical vector:

```
heights <- data.frame(height = 60:120)
ind <- heights$height > mean(heights$height)
```